# Maximise the Product

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I have an array consisting of positive and negative integers .
For the array i have to maximize the  quantity

$$\left| a_{i}-a_{j} \right| \left|i-j \right|$$

where $a_{i}$ is the $i_{th}  $ element in the array . The indexing of array is done starting with $ 1$.

What kind of approach should be applied to solve such problems .?

Comment: What are $a$, $i$, $j$, $ai$ ?  And are there any constraints on anything in your problem?  Must the array be finite?

Comment: Basically the problem misses to state what can be changed. If you want to maximize something, you must have several different 'configurations' from which to choose form. This isn't given in the statement, though I assume that it involes looking for permutations of the original array contents.

Comment: Yes , the array is finite.

Comment: maximizing varying what ? keeping constant what ?

Comment: Given an array like 5,6,3 with positions 1,2,3 for example, the expression $\left| a_{i}-a_{j} \right| \left|i-j \right|$ represents a fixed value - What is the variable that could be changed? Do you mean that you want to preposition the array elements of the array to achieve the optimal results? Please give an example.

Comment: I have to maximize  the quantity $$\left| a_{i}-a_{j} \right| \left|i-j \right|$$

where $i,j$ belongs to domain $ [1,n]$ where $n$ is the size of array , and 
$ i != j $ i.e compute the maximum possible value for expression mentioned above for all ordered pairs in the set.

Eg $5,2,3,10 $ the max value attained is $15$ taking elements at indices $1$ and $4$ .

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to compute them all.  If there are $n$ numbers in your array there are $\frac 12n(n-1)$ pairs to check.  The only improvement I can see is to start with the pairs that involve the end numbers so the $|i-j|$ factor is large.  Keep track of the largest and smallest numbers you find.  Then if you find a middling number in the middle of the array you can convince yourself not to compute the product for pairs which involve it.